# Запятая и тире

Tags: пунктуация

Пожалуйста, помогите расставить знаки препинания в предложении:

> Попробуйте присоединиться к его хобби,
> независимо от того, какими бы они вам
> не (или ни) представлялись, - просмотру
> или чтению боевиков, компьютерным
> играм, кулинарии и в них помогайте ему
> переживать ситуации успеха.

Comment: Верьясова, сочувствую Вам! Та-а-кое предложение, по-моему, никакими знаками препинания не спасёшь.

Comment: Да, не совсем понятно, как в хобби ( если я правильно понял), можно помочь человеку пережить ситуации успеха?! Да и само словосочетание ''ситуация успеха'' уже некорректно!

Comment: Мне кажется, что речь идет вот об этом термине: **Ситуация успеха**. https://spiritual_culture.academic.ru/2028/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0 Вполне возможно, что говорится о человеке с особыми потребностями (возможностями?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

М-да… Если же речь вести **ТОЛЬКО** о знаках препинания, то могу предложить такой вариант:

*Попробуйте присоединиться к его хобби (независимо от того, какими бы они вам ни представлялись!) -- просмотру или чтению боевиков, компьютерным играм, кулинарии -- и в них помогайте ему переживать ситуации успеха.*

Comment: Очень благодарна Вам.Спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: "Независимо от того" и "какими бы они вам ни" - конструкции одного и того же смысла (что-то здесь лишнее); возможны варианты:
"независимо от того, какими они вам представляются", либо "какими бы они вам ни представлялись".

Answer (score 4):

В предложении присутствует **обобщающее слово** "хобби", а за ним следует перечисление. В этом случае [следует использовать двоеточие](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_190), а не тире. Тире же идёт после однородных членов, когда предложение продолжается.

> Попробуйте присоединиться к его хобби (независимо от того, какими бы они вам ни представлялись): просмотру или чтению боевиков, компьютерным играм, кулинарии — и в них помогайте ему переживать ситуации успеха.

Или правильнее (без тавтологии):

> Попробуйте присоединиться к его хобби, какими бы они вам ни представлялись: просмотру или чтению боевиков, компьютерным играм, кулинарии — и в них помогайте ему переживать ситуации успеха.

Правда смысла предложению это всё равно не добавляет.